# How to append arrays in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I would like to get the output of this to be [1,2,3,4,...,200]. Any suggestions for how to go about this?

```
var Laser_data = 0;
var i = 0;
var j = 1;

int[] LaserData_200 = new int[200];

for (i = 0; i < LaserData_200.Length; i++)

{

 Laser_data += j;
 
 LaserData_200[i] = Laser_data;
 Console.WriteLine(" " + LaserData_200[i]);

}
```

Current output:

```
1

2

3

4

ect.
```

Comment: What is the purpose of j variable?

Comment: The posted code does not mention appending arrays, and the expected output matches the requirement (baring any formatting differences). Please explain what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 2):

Your array initialization and element assignment can be simplified massively. Your array is just the numbers 1 through 200 (inclusive). `Enumerable.Range` can generate that for you, then save it as an array.

```
int[] myArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 200).ToArray();
```

To print it all, `string.Join` it using a comma as a seperator.

```
Console.WriteLine($"[{string.Join(',', myArray)}]");
// [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13, .... 200]
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the title has nothing to do with the posted code.

So I am answering the question in the title.

Say you have two arrays `a` and `b` and you want to create a third array that combines the two arrays, then you write code like

```
int[] c = Enumerable.Concat(a, b).ToArray();
```

or you have and array `a` and you want to keep adding values to it in loop. When arrays are fixed size (`a.IsFixedSize = true` always) so you can do this efficiently.

The best solution is to use `List<T>` instead of an array

```
List<int> a = new List<int>() 
for(int i=0; i<200; i++)
{
    a.Add( i+1 );
}
```

and if you want an array in the end, you just do

```
int[] c= a.ToArray();
```